# Swift Package Manager could not be resolved all libraries, project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager, swift-package

[image]

This error always happens whenever I add a new Package via Swift Package Manager in Xcode:

> Cannot fetch library

I've already configured my GitHub Auth Token setting in Xcode and registered my GitHub account.

My macOS version is Monterey 12.1, my Xcode version is 13.1, my command-line tools are 13.1, and I'm using an M1 chipset Mac.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!
Please edit your question so that the error message is in the text instead of the image. This makes it more accessible and easier to find via search engines.

Also your question contains some malformed markup code, please fix that.

Answer (score 3):

## Configure Dependency Rule

### tl;dr

I encountered this issue today and managed to resolve the Package by changing the **Dependency Rule** from `Branch -> master` to **Up to Next Major Version** and checking their latest Release versions from GitHub.

### Other Dependency Rules

We can also try changing from Branch to other rules depending on our application:

1. Up to Next Major Version: Useful for getting the latest *major* stable release.
2. Up to Next Minor Version: Useful for getting the very latest releases.
3. Range of Versions: Useful for resolving dependencies specific to a particular dependency chain (careful configuration).
4. Exact Version: Useful for pinning a version to a particular working release, or fork.
5. Commit: Useful for pinning a Package to a commit rather than a release version.

### Xcode SPM "Add Package" prompt

[image: Xcode Add Package prompt]

Answer (score 0):

I tried to simulate your problem, Xcode and command-line version are the same. I was able to add SnapKit into my project without problems. Try this workaround:

Project -> Package Dependencies -> + -> paste the link: https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit -> Dependency rule set to Up To Next Major -> Add Package.

It should add a new package. Currently in version 5.0.1 If you have still a problem, just click Add Anyway, build the project and send a screenshot of the error.

Comment: hi juraj, thx for your comment. I followed your solution, but didn't work for me

Comment: I added another screen shot. this error always happened in Derived Data. I did remove all Derived Data, but problem wasn't not solved

Comment: @iostaeha, Try to click Add Anyway and build project, you should see a more detailed error description. I faced a similar problem. If that workaround above doesn't work, try to right-click on the package in that Recently Used Packages list and choose Remove Package. Repeat workaround.

Comment: I clicked Add Anyway, and added error message screen shot in my question

Comment: Showing Recent Messages

SnapKit
https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit: An unknown error occurred. '/Users/haba/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-hegqkymdqggryneilomohsbixdou/SourcePackages/repositories/SnapKit-4cdad746' exists and is not an empty directory (-4)

Fetching from https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit


Resolving Package Graph Failed    2021/12/12 9:06 PM    0.8 seconds